# Modify ResponseBytes using DotNetBrowser

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

Sample:

```
br.instance.engine.Network.ResponseBytesReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] data = e.Data;
                    string resp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                    resp = resp.Replace("old value", "new value");
                    byte[] newdata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp);
                    //e.Data = newdata;
                    
                }
                catch { }
            };
```

e.Data = newdata; - its imposible becouse only get

How we can transform this code? becouse need put modify real data before script context creating

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this code? maybe there is different approach available than altering event args state

Comment: need change attribute before script context creating